# Recursively split strings that contains a defined set of prefixes - Python

Tags: python, string, recursion, split, prefix

If i have a list of prefix that can be attached to a string, how do i split a string such into it's prefix and the other characters in the next substring. For example:

```
prefixes = ['over','under','re','un','co']

str1 = "overachieve"
output: ["over","achieve"]

str2 = "reundo"
output = ["re","un","do"]
```

Is there a better way to do the above task, maybe with regex or some string functions other than:

```
str1 = "reundo"
output = []

for x in [p for p in prefixes if p in str1]:
    output.append(x)    
    str1 =  str1.replace(x,"",1)
output.append(str1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular expressions are an efficient way to search for many alternative prefixes:

```
import re

def split_prefixes(word, prefixes):
    regex = re.compile('|'.join(sorted(prefixes, key=len, reverse=True)))
    result = []
    i = 0
    while True:
        mo = regex.match(word, i)
        if mo is None:
            result.append(word[i:])
            return result
        result.append(mo.group())
        i = mo.end()


>>> prefixes = ['over', 'under', 're', 'un', 'co']
>>> for word in ['overachieve', 'reundo', 'empire', 'coprocessor']:
        print word, '-->', split_prefixes(word, prefixes)

overachieve --> ['over', 'achieve']
reundo --> ['re', 'un', 'do']
empire --> ['empire']
coprocessor --> ['co', 'processor']
```

Comment: +1 for `match(word, i)`, I never noticed that `match` also has `pos` and `endpos`.

Comment: but there is a problem with `underachieve`, i end up getting `["un","under","achieve"]` =)

Comment: Hmm, it works for me.  ``split_prefixes('underachieve', ['over', 'under', 're', 'un', 'co']) --> ['under', 'achieve']``

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `str.startswith` method

```
for p in prefixes:
    if str1.startswith(p):
        output.append(p)
        str1 = str1.replace(p, '', 1)
output.append(str1)
```

The biggest flaw with your code is that strings like `'found'` will output `['un', 'fod']`.

However if you have a hypothetical string `'reuncoundo'`, then you'll need to iterate over the list more than once.

```
while True:
    if not any(str1.startswith(i) for i in prefixes):
        output.append(str1)
        break
    for p in prefixes:
        if str1.startswith(p):
            output.append(p)
            str1 = str1.replace(p, '', 1)
```

This outputs `['re', 'un', 'co', 'un', 'do']`

Comment: What about the hypothetical input `"reuncoundo"`? Your code would miss the second `"un"`, surely?

Comment: @Drakekin just addressed that issue

Answer (score 1):

```
prefixes = ['over','under','re','un','co']

def test(string, prefixes, existing=None):
    prefixes.sort(key = lambda s: len(s))
    prefixes.reverse() # This and the previous line ensure that longer prefixes are searched first regardless of initial sorting.
    if existing is None:
        existing = [] # deals with the fact that placing [] as a default parameter and modifying it modifies it for the entire session
    for prefix in prefixes:
        if string.startswith(prefix):
            existing.append(prefix)
            return test(string[len(prefix):], prefixes, existing)
    existing.append(string)
    return existing
```

This code runs through a string recursively, removing known prefixes until it runs out, then returning the entire list. On longer strings, the generator is probably a better route, but on shorter strings the lack of need for the additional overhead of a generator might make this a better solution.

Comment: Can you confirm the "additional overhead of a generator"? I'd be more concerned with the additional overhead of recursion in this case. (minor remark)

Comment: I was half referring to the addition of the requirement to turn the generator output into a list (instead of an iterable) but also the (probably perceived) mental overhead of a generator. A lot of the people I work and study with consider them basically magic.

Comment: I encourage everyone to get acquainted with generators, there are generall (and even have leaked into C#). That said, if you insist on returning a list, the simplest way to rewrite a generator is to make a `result = []` and replace `yield foo` with `result.append(foo)`. Python doesn't fold tail recursion, but you may :). I don't recommend avoiding generators though; note how happily Python 3 uses iterables everywhere. It's just a nice concept to work with.

Comment: I keep putting off actually using generators more simple than `[foo(x) for x in bar]`. I think this might be the kick up the backside to start trying harder.

Answer (score 1):

Having the "two problems" proverb in mind, I'd still say this is the job for a regular expression. Regexes compile to state machines which check all possible variants in parallel, not one-by-one.

Here's an implementation that leverages that:

```
import re

def split_string(string, prefixes):
    regex = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, prefixes))) # (1)
    while True:
        match = regex.match(string)
        if not match:
            break
        end = match.end()
        yield string[:end]
        string = string[end:]
    if string:
        yield string # (2)

prefixes = ['over','under','re','un','co']
assert (list(split_string('recouncoundo',prefixes))
        == ['re','co','un','co','un','do'])
```

Note how the regular expression is constructed in (1):

- the prefixes are escaped using `re.escape` so that special characters don't interfere
- the escaped prefixes are joined using the `|` (or) regex operator
- the whole thing gets compiled.

The line (2) yields the final word, if any is left over after splitting prefixes. You might want to remove the `if string` check if you want the function to return an empty string if nothing remains after prefix stripping.

Also note that `re.match` (contrary to `re.search`) only looks for the pattern at the beginning of the input string, so there's no need to append `^` to the regex.

Comment: Python regexes (like most other current regex engines) do check all possible variants in sequence, not in parallel. Therefore, order of the variants matters. For example `(re|reun)` would split `reundo` in `re` and `undo`, not `reun` and `do` as a DFA regex engine (leftmost-longest rule) would.

Comment: What I meant was that the regex would check the first letter first, and having discovered `r` it would proceed check `re` and `reun` but not `over` or `under`. Hence I'd expect it to work faster than a repeated `for p in prefix`-style solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with prefixes, you don't need regex, you only need `startswith()`. You can of course use regex, but it's harder to read and maintain, even for an easy one like this. `startswith()` is simpler, in my opinion.

And the other answers seems too complicated for such a simple problem. I'd suggest a recursive function like this one:

```
def split_prefixes (word, prefixes):
    split = [p for p in prefixes if word.startswith(p)]
    if split:
        return split + split_prefixes (word[len(split[0]):], prefixes)
    else:
        return [word]
```

This is the result:

```
"overachieve" -> ['over', 'achieve']
"reundo" -> ['re', 'un', 'do']
"reuncoundo" -> ['re', 'un', 'co', 'un', 'do']
"empire" -> ['empire']
```